# Raspberry pi randomly disconnects my wlan0 but keeps working through eth0 and even wlan1

Tags: pi-3, wifi, wireless

I have a raspberry pi 3 which will randomly disconnect from my wifi network. If I do `ifconfig` I can see that `wlan0` has no IP address anymore. However, `eth0` still has and my wifi dongle in `wlan1` also has.

How can I debug this problem?

The only thing unusual in my setup is that I have multiple wireless stations with the same SSID through the house, but I don't think this is a problem.

**UPDATE:**

My `ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:4b:27:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.115/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::82d5:a04b:8a68:c6e0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:1e:72:3b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 20:e5:17:06:b3:df brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.117/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::cdec:88b5:90aa:d03e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:e2:5e:5a:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.18.64/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::34cd:c165:f0f6:55dc/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: veth4d711fc@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:26:c3:69:d3:69 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 169.254.220.88/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global veth4d711fc
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ec26:c3ff:fe69:d369/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: You have to add more detail - how you configured the network, **WHY** you have 2 WiFi cards, what the current output of `ip a` is (`ifconfig` is deprecated). Using multiple cards WITHOUT [predictable network interface names](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#new-interface-names) is unreliable

Comment: @Milliways I updated with my output. I forgot to say that the problem still happens without the other wifi card, I just added to test

Comment: Seems to be a complicated setup with wired ethernet, two wifi connections, with docker and an additional virtual interface: 5 interfaces (except lo). Do you have two different access points you connect to one with **wlan0** and to the other with **wlan1**?

Comment: @Ingo I only have one access point, and the problem happens without wlan1

Comment: I don't understand. As shown with `ip addr` the problem happens **with** wlan1 when wlan0 is down. For what do you need two wifi interfaces? What do you expect what ip address wlan0 should have? Does both interfaces shall connect to the same access point?